# Installing gnuplot (or similar) on Lion

Tags: macos, macports, unix, fink, open-source

All the packages needed to install gnuplot through MacPorts on Lion succeed, except for aquaterm.

Installing gnuplot through Fink is far less lucky on Lion. Fink bails out after only a third of the packages needed for gnuplot have been installed, but Fink does install aquaterm.

Is there a way to 'port install gnuplot' while pointing MacPorts to the aquaterm installation generated by Fink?

Also nice would be to know of a method to install gnuplot on Lion that uses neither Fink nor MacPorts. Learning about a replacement for gnuplot itself on OSX would be handy.

Comment: What is the error on macports's aquaterm - fixing this would probably be easier than mixing Fink and macports

Comment: I dunno what you're using Gnuplot for, but perhaps Apple's Grapher app can do what you need? It's bundled with OS X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install gnuplot. I believe I had to use specify --nolua. First, I installed aqua term:
`brew install aquaterm`. Then I installed gnuplot with `brew install gnuplot --nolua` and that was it, gnuplot picked up aquaterm immediately.

Additionally, I sometimes use [octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) to plot. It's also got a formula in Homebrew, so just run `brew install octave` and away you go!

Comment: Very nice. Homebrew installed gnuplot with no trouble and with what seems to be a fraction of the dependencies, but that could be because it is willing to use packages that are already installed (neither Fink nor MacPorts will do so). I didn't have to use --nolua, but again, brew may have used one that was already installed. Octave also seems nice, but it can't do least-squares fitting to an arbitrary function, one of the features I need.

Answer (score 1):

Download [Maxima](http://sourceforge.net/projects/maxima/files/Maxima-MacOS/5.26.0-MacOSX/). It contains a working Gnuplot.app for Lion.